# NHibernate entity projection

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, criteria-api, queryover

I'm using NHibernate with QueryOver API to query my domain entities. The problem is getting duplicate results. For example when querying following domain:
[image: domain]

I use code like:

```
  var list = Session.QueryOver<Post>()
                    .JoinQueryOver<Comment>(x => x.Comments)
                    .Where(c => c.Name == "Name")
                    .Take(5)
                    .List();
```

Generated SQL will be like following:

```
SELECT Top(5) * FROM Posts p left outer join Comments c on p.Id = c.PostId
```

The problem here is that after left join is done resulting record set has more then 5 rows. And then `TOP` function applies and cuts results. So for example if first post has 5 comments, I will get this post 5 times and won't get others.

I know why it happens and found a nice [post](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/get-unique-results-from-joined-queries.aspx) about it. 
But Is there a projection that will tell nhibernate to select only columns from the `Post` entity and not add columns from `Comment` entity in select? Maybe some other method (not JoinQueryOver) should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need a reference back from Comment to Post. I'll assume it's called "Post".

Then use a subquery to filter out the comments, and subsequent posts.

```
//the alias for post
Post post = null; 

var list = Session.QueryOver(() => post)
            .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(() => post.Id)
                .In(NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver.Of<Comment>()
                    .Where(c => c.Name == "Name")
                    .Select(c => c.Post.Id))
            .Take(5)
            .List();
```

The generated SQL should be something in the likes of:

```
SELECT Top(5) * FROM Posts p where p.Id in (select PostID from Comments c where c.Name = 'Name')
```

Comment: Yes, in my application I ended up with subquery. Is there a prjection to get only results from one table?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The example that I wrote only returns results from one table, the "Posts" one. The inner select only filters the posts which have comments with the name "Name"

Comment: I want have something like Select distinct Post.* from Posts p inner join Comments c

Comment: Have you tried my code? It should do what's required as there's no join to the Comments table, hence no cartesian product. The "select *" will only target the Posts table. Anyway, if you really require the query to be as you stated (with the inner join), then you'll probably have to stick with HQL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid duplication in the results of join you can use the Transformer DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer this transformer will remove the duplication from the posts but it will not remove the duplication from the comments if they are joined with another entity. In this situation, you will have to develop your own transformer to remove the duplications on the second level.

Answer (score -2):

we have used   criteria.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()); to avoid duplicate records.

Comment: Why not map to an ISet instead?